# how to add one to all fields in a file

Tags: bash

suppose I have file containing numbers like:

```
1 4 7  
2 5 8
```

and I want to add `1` to all these numbers, making the output like:

```
2 5 8  
3 6 9
```

is there a simple one-line command (e.g. awk) to realize this?

Comment: *grumble* re: the one-liner request -- there's often something given up (correctness, readability, corner-case handling, startup-time performance, etc) in making an answer a one-liner; requesting a one-liner explicitly is thus prioritising terseness over whatever compromises might be necessary to achieve it.

Comment: See [codegolf.se] if you're looking for a site for "Code Golf" puzzles (which is to say, "what's the shortest possible way to write an implementation of X?"). That site **exists** because we booted such puzzles off StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much for this insightful comment! I just realized a corner-case of dealing with floating numbers. This solution does not work with numbers like 1.001 and will mistakenly produce an output of 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind `Perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1+1/eg' file
```

Substitute any number composed of multiple digits (`\d+`) with that number (`$1`) plus 1. `/e` means to execute the replacement calculation, and `/g` means globally throughout the file.

As mentioned in the comments, the above only works for positive integers - per the OP's original sample file. If you wanted it to work with negative numbers, decimals and still retain text and spacing, you could go for something like this:

```
perl -pe 's/([-]?[.0-9]+)/$1+1/eg' file
```

**Input file**

```
Some column headers   # words
1 4 7                 # a comment
2       5 cat     dog # spacing and stray words
+5 0                  # plus sign
-7 4                  # minus sign
+1000.6               # positive decimal
-21.789               # negative decimal
```

**Output**

```
Some column headers   # words
2 5 8                 # a comment
3       6 cat     dog # spacing and stray words
+6 1                  # plus sign
-6 5                  # minus sign
+1001.6               # positive decimal
-20.789               # negative decimal
```

Comment: This solution does not work with float numbers like 1.001 and will mistakenly produce an output of 2.1

Comment: @zhihao_li Yes, that is correct - it says exactly that too - *”any number composed of multiple digits”* - it will not work for negative numbers (as they are not composed of digits since they have minus signs), nor will it work for numbers in scientific notation, nor for complex numbers but OP’s example implies positive integers. Thank you for making it clear.

Comment: @zhihao_li The other `awk` solutions will mess up any text in column headers as will the `bash` solution which will also not work with floats, or scientific notation...

Comment: @zhihao_li I added some more thought to my answer in the light of your comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try following once.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=$i+1}} 1'   Input_file
```

**EDIT:** As per OP's request without loop, here is a solution(written as per shown sample only).

```
With hardcoding of number of fields.
awk -v RS='[ \n]' '{ORS=NR%3==0?"\n":" ";print $0+1}'  Input_file

OR

Without hardcoding number of fields.
awk -v RS='[ \n]' -v col=$(awk 'FNR==1{print NF}' Input_file) '{ORS=NR%col==0?"\n":" ";print $0+1}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** So in EDIT section 1st solution I have hardcoded the number of fields by mentioning 3 there, in OR solution of EDIT, I am creating a variable named col which will read the very first line of Input_file to get the number of fields. Then it will not read all the Input_file, Now coming onto the code I have set Record separator as space or new line to it will add them without using a loop and it will add space each time after incrementing 1 in their values. It will print new line only when number of lines are completely divided by value of col(which is why we have taken number of fields in -v col section).

Comment: Personally, I might put a `; print` inside the existing block after the `for` loop ends rather than a separate `1` to be always-true with the default `{print}` block -- it's not immediately obvious to a reader how this works unless they know more `awk` than many folks do.

Comment: Thanks! I wanna check and see if there is a solution even without using a loop.

Comment: @zhihao_li, **every** solution will use a loop, even if that loop is implicit. Here, there are two loops -- the implicit one over each line, and the explicit one over each field. (Personally, I've spent enough time following Python dogma to believe that explicit is better than implicit -- ie. that it's more important that code be easy for a reader to understand than that it be terse; we have a separate site for code golf puzzles, where being short is more important than anything else).

Comment: @zhihao_li: could you please check my edit now, I added 2 solutions now. So first solution we have to give number of fields there where I have given 3, in second solution code will automatically take number of fields from the Input_file by reading it's 1st file itself. Let me know if you are happy with this :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand implicit loops but simply want to avoid explicit ones to make succinct codes. If you are familiar with tools like Matlab, this kind of matrix operation is as easy as "A=A+1" with A being the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In native bash (no `awk` or other external tool needed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r -a nums; do      # read a line into an array, splitting on spaces
  out=( )                      # initialize an empty output array for that line
  for num in "${nums[@]}"; do  # iterate over the input array...
    out+=( "$(( num + 1 ))" )  # ...and add n+1 to the output array.
  done
  printf '%s\n' "${out[*]}"    # then print that output array with a newline following
done <in.txt >out.txt          # with input from in.txt and output to out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using gnu awk:

```
awk -v RS="[[:space:]]+" '{$0++; ORS=RT} 1' file

2 5 8
3 6 9
```